Invalid or Unexpected Token' in env.mjs
I keep getting this error message '5173/node_modules/v…st/client/env.mjs:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token' in my browser when i try to run my vite application
I have tried changing the url to my backend in my env file and i also did some config settings
this is my viteconfig file
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['env.mjs'],
  },
  plugins: [react()],
})


Do you have dotenv installed. Have you added dotenv.config() anywhere?

no, but the code has been working for over a month. it just suddenly stopped working

Have you added or updated any packages  recently? Especially auth related packages.
